# How can I send an ajax request and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen the following sequence in my client code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    data: {},
    success: function() {
    // I don't care about the response
    }
});

top.location.href="http://...."
```

As you can see the browser send an ajax request, and doesn't care about the response. 
after it sends the request the page is redirected to another url using the `top.location.href` statement .

I am a newbie in javascript and I am not sure if the ajax request is guaranteed to be sent?

Is there another approach to get this *send and forget and redirect* ajax behavior?

**EDIT**:

Just to clarify, I do not want to wait for this ajax to finish it's long operation and put the redirection line in the success callback.

Comment: I am talking about the client side, can It be that the ajax function will get queued on the browser and the top.location.href will run before it?

Comment: thats why, if you dont want it to run before ur ajax request, put it in success or complete parameter of ajax.

Comment: check this page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be 100% sure that the message was received and processed, you should do your redirect in the `success` handler.

This would also enable you to do error handling if that is required - for example, what if you make the AJAX request but it fails for some reason? If you just redirect the user would never know there was a problem. But maybe you do not need to care about this depending upon this specifics of your application.

Comment: The thing is, if you redirect before your request reaches the server, then it might be lost. So at a minimum I would suggest making the AJAX request and then using `setTimeout` to wait a second or so before you redirect. But that is error-prone because you are still relying on timing - and what if it takes a longer time for your request to make it back to the server? A better approach would be to modify your server handler to return immediately and queue a job to run on the server to complete the long-running task. Then you could still use the `success` handler on the client. Does that help?

Comment: +1 It sounds like the most reasonable thing to do, I was looking for a short answer like "it will work". somewhere I knew I wouldn't get it :) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to redirect to some other page after ajax request is successful then why dont you put your top.location in success function or if you just want to redirect regardless your ajax is succeeded or not...write your top.location in a function of complete parameter.